# How can I import/open the Twilio android code in the same Android Studio where I already have the ionic and capacitor code opened?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, twilio, capacitor

I have Ionic and Capacitor code imported opened in Android Studio. I am trying to open Twilio SDK in the same Android studio. But it's not letting me do that and the Twilio SDK is opening in a new Android studio. Am I missing something?

Then only I can integrate them right? Is my understanding correct?

I am trying to do the following in android studio:

```
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call;
```

It says "cannot resolve symbol twilio"

Comment: First, you have to add dependency of Twilio SDK in your build.gradle  or  you can import module of Twilio SDK to your current project after syncing the changes add Twilio dependency in the code. Currently, your project doesn't have access to Twilio  SDK.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to import twilio using gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio Java SDK is not intended for use within Android applications and will not work.

Further, you should not make requests directly to the Twilio API from an Android application. To do so you would need to either store or retrieve your Twilio account credentials within your application. A malicious user could then extract the credentials from the application and use them to abuse your account and spend your credit.

Instead, we recommend you build a server application that your Android app can use as a proxy to the Twilio API. Check out this blog post on [how to send SMS messages from Android with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html) to see an example.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I will check this as well. I am trying to use Twilio credentials - I have environment variables and I am trying to access through that.